# From Reissner-Nordstrom to Dilatonic Gravity and Einstein Equation

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, action

I am doing some calculations of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08482 and in particular I am having trouble with 2 parts:

Dimensional Reduction (16):
I have managed to get equation (16) from the dimensional reduction of (14) (I will ignore the electromagnetic contribution):
We start from
\begin{equation}
S = \frac{1}{l_P^2}\int d^4x \sqrt{-g} R_g
\end{equation}
Use the warped product space
\begin{equation} ds^2 = h_{ij}dx^idx^j + e^{2\psi}d\Omega^2 \end{equation}
To find
\begin{equation} \sqrt{-g} = \sqrt{-h} e^{2\psi} \sin(\theta) \end{equation}
The angular coordinates can be integrated out and gives $4\pi$.
The Ricci scalar from a warped product space can be found in this reference [http://people.brandeis.edu/~headrick/HeadrickCompendium.pdf](http://people.brandeis.edu/%7Eheadrick/HeadrickCompendium.pdf)
\begin{align}
ds^2 &= h_{ij} dx^i dx^j + e^{2\psi} g_{\mu \nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu \\
R &= R_h + e^{-2 \psi}R_g - 2 k \nabla^2_h \psi - k(k+1) h^{ij}\partial_i \psi \partial_j \psi
\end{align}
where $k$ gives the dimensionality of the second metric.
In our case with the second metric being a sphere, this would result in
\begin{equation}
R = R_h + 2 e^{-2\psi} - 6 (\partial \psi)^2-4\nabla^2_h \psi
\end{equation}
The last term gives a boundary contribution.
Plugging this in we get
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{4\pi}{l_P^2}\int dt dx \sqrt{-h} [e^{2\psi}(R_h - 6 (\partial \psi)^2) + 2]
\end{equation}
However, the correct action should be with $2(\partial \psi)^2$.
Where did I go wrong? They also stated they had to use partial integration?

Equation of motion for $h_{++}$:
I also couldn't find how they got (19).
The Einstein equation I got from varying the action (17) where I put all the field terms in a seperate Lagrangian and only looked at the term with the Ricci scalar:
\begin{equation}
\Phi^2 R^h_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2}\Phi^2 R^h h_{\mu \nu} = 16 \pi G_N T_{\mu \nu}
\end{equation}
from
\begin{equation}
I = \frac{1}{16\pi G_N} \int d^2x \sqrt{-h} \Phi^2 R^h + S_{matter}
\end{equation}
I don't see how the equation for $h_{++}$ reduces to
\begin{equation} -e^{2\omega} \partial_+ (e^{-2\omega} \partial_+ \Phi^2) = T_{++}
\end{equation}
in the conformal gauge
\begin{equation} ds^2 = -e^{2\omega}du^+ du^- \end{equation}

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: before integrating by parts the last term in your decomposition of $R$, did you take into account the $e^{2\psi}$ contribution coming from the metric determinant?

Comment: Good point! This would indeed result in a +8, but it doesn't explain how the $\nabla_h$ would suddenly become a $\partial$.

Comment: is $\nabla_h$ a spacetime covariant derivative? If so, acting on a scalar it reduces to a partial.

Comment: That's true and resolves the first part, thank you very much!